# Ejecutar un boton solo una vez

Tags: html

Hola amigo quisiera ejecutar un boton solo una vez y que ya no se pueda dar otra vez click en Aceptar

```html
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancelarPreviewFlashReport" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="AgregarPreviewFlashReport" name="AgregarPreviewFlashReport"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Aceptar</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: quizas te refieras al metodo one de jquery https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_one.asp

Answer (score 6):

Es necesario que agregues `Javascript` en este caso usar `JQuery` que al darle `click()` al botón que necesites se deshabilite, identificándolo por el `ID`.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

```js
$( "#btnCancelarPreviewFlashReport" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});

$( "#AgregarPreviewFlashReport" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancelarPreviewFlashReport" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="AgregarPreviewFlashReport" name="AgregarPreviewFlashReport"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Aceptar</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer también con Javascript puro, sin necesidad de librerías externas.

Por ejemplo, para deshabilitar el botón aceptar:

```js
var btnAceptar=document.getElementById("AgregarPreviewFlashReport");
var disableButton = function() { this.disabled = true; };
btnAceptar.addEventListener('click', disableButton , false);
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancelarPreviewFlashReport" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="AgregarPreviewFlashReport" name="AgregarPreviewFlashReport"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Aceptar</button>
</div>
```

Si se necesitara hacer lo mismo con el botón `Cancelar` bastaría con crear una referencia al elemento y asignarle el listener:

```
var btnCancelar=document.getElementById("btnCancelarPreviewFlashReport");
btnCancelar.addEventListener('click', disableButton , false);
```

Si son muchos elementos, se pueden seleccionar todos mediante una clase y asignarles el listener dentro de un `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo con Jquery de esta manera:

```
$('#AgregarPreviewFlashReport').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Una consulta donde puedo poner el query en el mismo archivo o en otro , alquien me podria dar un ejemplo porfa

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPreviewFlashReport" accesskey="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancelarPreviewFlashReport" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="AgregarPreviewFlashReport" name="AgregarPreviewFlashReport"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Aceptar</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: En base a la respuesta de @AlejandroGonzalez, un ejemplo valido sería así:
[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/3x6d5g21/)